# React Invalid Hook Call in Index.js in ReactDOM.render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This problem is killing me, but I keep getting this error when I compile and run (I am using .NET Core 3.0 with react app):

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

The error points to my ../src/index.js file:

Here is the error displayed
[image]

Here is the code that is flagged with the invalid hook call error
[image]

I'm not sure what's going on, i spent the past 3 hours trying to fix it but I just can't get the homepage to show.

I understand the hooks error, but I don't understand why its getting called.

1. I have the matching versions of React and React DOM, 16.13.1
2. For my react components, I use classes.
3. I'm not sure how to check for different copies of react

I'm quite new to React so maybe i misunderstood or messed up somewhere, please help me here, thank you.

EDIT:

Comment: Will you please also post the code for `App` component

Comment: The error is exactly what it says, you are telling us you using class components, and the error states "**use hooks only in function components**"

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont quite understand, so does that mean I have to switch over to using functions and hooks or can I stick with my classes? If I do stick with my classes, do I have to go back to the older versions of react before hooks was introduced? like <react16.8.0

Comment: You don't need to switch versions. One of your Route paths using hooks inside a class which is not allowed. Please avoid posting pictures, better to paste actual code or upload to demo to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)

Comment: Try searching (in your IDE) for `use` keyword... Like `useHook`, `useEffect` etc.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the picture spam.

I checked with all the js files, no usage of useHook, useEffect, useState etc.
I removed all the route path except the Home.js and I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you post your `App.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Check if redux is installed on the client. This error occurs when it isn't installed on client directory but server directory.

check package.json of client.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a crazy solution but in my case nothing was actually wrong with my code. I was going nuts trying to find the error. But what actually helped, was upgrading the version of Typescript installed in my project from 4.4 to 4.9. Don't see any evident connection but after the upgrade everything worked like a charm. :)